# How to change variable type on runtime

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a `tableview` that want to display different `UITableViewCell's` depending on a datasource identifier.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell : AnyObject

    var itemDic = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! [String : String];

    switch itemDic["celltype"]! as String {
    case "dash":

        cell = tblGraphs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DashboardCell") as! DashboardTableViewCell
        cell.setData(itemDic, indexPath: indexPath)
    case "chart":

    cell = tblGraphs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChartCell") as! ChartTableViewCell

    default:

        cell = tblGraphs.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DashboardCell") as! DashboardTableViewCell

    }


    return cell
}
```

Of course is giving me an error:

[image]

Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: I might be missing something, but why not just `var cell : UITableViewCell` instead?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var cell : AnyObject
```

with

```
var cell : UITableViewCell!
```

otherwise it doesn't know that you are trying to return a UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

actually you have taken cell variable of type anyobject type but that method return a object of UITableViewcell.
if you have different type of cells than you have to take that variable of type "UITableViewcell" it would work like anyobject in this method.